# ContainerRequestState [INFO] No more pending requests in queue

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming, mapr, apache-samza

I am using a MapR (YARN) cluster with 3 nodes. I am trying to deploy 6 Samza jobs on the cluster for some processing on data streams. All jobs are correct. I tried deploying 2-3 in parallel and they work. 
However when I deploy all the 6 Samza jobs in parallel I see following logs. The tasks continue to run and dont produce expected output data stream.

[image]

The status of the nodes on my ResourceManager web dashboard is as follows-
[image]

Can anyone suggest how can this be resolved. I think that maybe the application does not have sufficient resources to run all of them in parallel. What change can I try?

Comment: Can you show your configuration of Hadoop cluster. How many vCore, memory... Because each container need 1 core and each Samza worker need 1024mb (default) memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
no more pending requests in queue.
```

This message means that still more messages in your Kafka Topic.